# Sensory Chess Board

Tags: digital-logic, rfid, manufacturing, production

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Detecting object placement on a grid](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32293/detecting-object-placement-on-a-grid)

How could a checkered chess board be built so that it **knows** the **location** of the **pieces**? What options are available? Probably **RFID** chips? It'd have to be **sensitive** enough to detect movement from one square to another.

Please order the options from cheapest to most expensive to **mass produce**.

Thanks!

Comment: RFID is not likely to be the best solution due to the proximity of the pieces and the board.

Comment: Tyler, the problem is that while the problem you face is interesting, asking for a set of complete solutions, sorted in various ways and without showing some research, make it seems like you want others to work for you. It may not be the case, but show some more effort and make it more specific. Luckily there was a similar question that you can take as example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have tower, horse, knight, king, queen and pion. That 6 figures in black or white variant give you 12 figures which is a number that can fit in 4 bits. You will need 5 contacts on the bottom of each square. One with constant voltage source (like +5V or +3.3V, depending on your MCU), and four contacts that go into digital inputs of your MCU (probably via some GPIO extender chip). Each figure will then internally electrically connect +V to those 4 pins, making for each figure type a binary unique number that can be read by MCU. Polling these 4 bits in all 64 squares MCU will exactly know what figure is on what square. Everyone is licensed to use this idea for non profit goals. Commercial use of this idea costs 5000 dollars. Your move. ;-)